# How to migrate a filtered portion of a GMail mailbox toward an Outlook 365 mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, office365

I have a GMail mailbox which has been receiving email from both `johnfoobar@gmail.com` (the default address) and `johnfoobar@contoso.com` (Contoso being a 3rd-party domain).

I would like to migrate all the emails that were even sent to `johnfoobar@contoso.com` toward a dedicated Outlook 365 account (which will become the primary recipient for `johnfoobar@contoso.com`).

I do not want to move all the emails of the mailbox `johnfoobar@gmail.com`, only those where `contoso.com` appears anywhere. The whole email history has to be processed, not just the newer incoming emails.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do suggestion above help? If the issue has been resolved, you could mark the helpful reply as best answer or share your solution, your action will be helpful other people who encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a filter mails in gmail and move these mails to one specific folder. Detailed step for your reference: [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en#zippy=%2Cexport-or-import-filters%2Ccreate-a-filter%2Cedit-or-delete-filters)

Then you could follow the [guidance](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-gmail-to-outlook-20fdb8f2-fed8-4b14-baf0-bf04b9c44bf7) to import mails to outlook.

Comment: Unfortunately, filters only apply to newer emails as they are received, not the whole email history.